VBA Windows Automation, Possible Invoke Issue
I am an ammeter Coder, and come up with the following code that lets me rearrange the Spec Tree in Catia via an Excel UserForm.
This works great most of the time, but occasionally it does not put arrange my spec tree correctly, I believe the issue is with my last section where I Invoke all the patters.
I think it it might be missing a few Invokes randomly through the code processing.
The only way I could get it to work when testing it was to Incorporate a delay between each Invoke, with my "Waste Time" feature.
But I have a feeling I am not doing this the best way, can someone please help me optimize and possible eliminate the bugs that it appears to have?
Sub ApplyOrderToCatiaForm()

 Dim CATIA, doc, prod, sel
    
    Dim pctDone As Double
    Dim iLabelWidth As Integer
    iLabelWidth = 366
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet ', wsB1 As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook ', wbB As Workbook
    
    Set CATIA = GetObject(, "CATIA.Application")    ' get CATIA Application
    Set doc = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    Set prod = doc.Product
    Set sel = doc.Selection
    'Debug.Print CATIA.Caption
    
    ' select top product in a CATIA tree
    sel.Clear
    sel.Add prod
    
    ' launch "Graph tree reordering" command
    CATIA.StartCommand "Graph tree reordering"
    
    
    Dim winAutomation As CUIAutomation
    Set winAutomation = New CUIAutomation
    
    Dim desktop As IUIAutomationElement
    ' get reference to the root element (desktop)
    Set desktop = winAutomation.GetRootElement
    
    Dim allWindowsCond As IUIAutomationCondition
    ' retrieves a predefined condition that selects all elements
    Set allWindowsCond = winAutomation.CreateTrueCondition
    
    Dim childs As IUIAutomationElementArray
    ' find all elements & put them into element array
    Set childs = desktop.FindAll(TreeScope_Children, allWindowsCond)
    
    Dim i As Long, currChild As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim catiaWindow As IUIAutomationElement
    
    ' loop through all element and find CATIA by window name which contains "CATIA V5" string
    For i = 0 To childs.Length - 1
        Set currChild = childs.GetElement(i)
        
        'If InStr(currChild.CurrentName, "CATIA V5-R2021") Then
        If InStr(currChild.CurrentName, CATIA.Caption) Then
            Set catiaWindow = currChild ' set main catia window
            i = childs.Length - 1
        End If
        'Debug.Print currChild.CurrentName, currChild.CurrentClassName
        
    Next

    Dim graphWinCond As IUIAutomationCondition
    Set graphWinCond = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Graph tree reordering")
    
    Dim graphWin As IUIAutomationElement
    
    'wait for Graph window to open and get it
    Do
        Set graphWin = catiaWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, graphWinCond)
        
         'do not freeze application in case of infinite loop
        DoEvents
    Loop While graphWin Is Nothing       
    
    ' get OK button
    Dim btnOKCondition As IUIAutomationCondition, btnOk As IUIAutomationElement
    
    Set btnOKCondition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "OK")
    Set btnOk = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Children, btnOKCondition)
        
    ' get Free Move button
    Dim btnFreeMoveCondition As IUIAutomationCondition, btnFreeMove As IUIAutomationElement

    Set btnFreeMoveCondition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Free Move")
    Set btnFreeMove = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, btnFreeMoveCondition)

    ' control pattern definition (button click)
    Dim patOK As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Dim patFreeMove As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    Dim selectPart As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
    
    Set patOK = btnOk.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    Set patFreeMove = btnFreeMove.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    
    ' select First Part In Menu
    Dim btnProd1Condition As IUIAutomationCondition, btnProd1 As IUIAutomationElement
    Dim btnProd2Condition As IUIAutomationCondition, btnProd2 As IUIAutomationElement
       
    'Create Excel Arrays
    Dim BeforeArrangeList() As Variant
    Dim AfterArrangeList() As Variant
    
    BeforeArrangeList = frmSorter.listCurrentSpecTree.List
    AfterArrangeList = frmSorter.listNewSpecTree.List      
    
    BeforeArrangeList = frmSorter.listCurrentSpecTree.List
    AfterArrangeList = frmSorter.listNewSpecTree.List
        
    Dim NumElementsBefore As Long
    Dim NumElementsAfter As Long

    NumElementsBefore = UBound(BeforeArrangeList) - LBound(BeforeArrangeList) + 1
    NumElementsAfter = UBound(AfterArrangeList) - LBound(AfterArrangeList) + 1    
    
    Set btnProd1Condition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, AfterArrangeList(NumElementsAfter - 1, 0))
    Set btnProd2Condition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, BeforeArrangeList(0, 0))
        
    Set btnProd1 = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, btnProd1Condition)
    Set btnProd2 = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, btnProd2Condition)
    
    Set selectPart = btnProd1.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
        
    selectPart.Invoke
    
    WasteTime (1)
    
    patFreeMove.Invoke
    
    WasteTime (1)
    
    Set selectPart = btnProd2.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    
    WasteTime (1)

    selectPart.Invoke
    
    WasteTime (1)   
    
    Dim Z As Long
    Dim SelectProd As IUIAutomationElement
    
    ' loop through all element
    For Z = 0 To NumElementsAfter - 1
    
    If Z = NumElementsAfter - 1 Then GoTo Finish
    
    Set btnProd1Condition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, AfterArrangeList(Z, 0))
    Set btnProd2Condition = winAutomation.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, AfterArrangeList(NumElementsAfter - 1, 0))
    
    Set btnProd1 = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, btnProd1Condition)
    Set btnProd2 = graphWin.FindFirst(TreeScope_Descendants, btnProd2Condition)
    
    Set selectPart = btnProd1.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
        
    selectPart.Invoke
    
    WasteTime (1)
    
    patFreeMove.Invoke
    
    WasteTime (1)
    
    Set selectPart = btnProd2.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
    
    WasteTime (1)

    selectPart.Invoke
    
    WasteTime (1)
    
    'Debug.Print Z, AfterArrangeList(Z, 0)
    
                ProgressMenu.lblStatus1.Caption = ("Moving Part " & Z & " of " & NumElementsAfter - 2)
                pctDone = Z / (NumElementsAfter - 2)
                ProgressMenu.lblProgress.Width = iLabelWidth * pctDone
                DoEvents
                ProgressMenu.FrameProgress.Caption = Format(pctDone, "0%")
    
Finish:
    
    Next
    
    ProgressMenu.Hide
    MsgBox "All Done"
    patOK.Invoke
    
    
End Sub

Sub WasteTime(Time As Long)

    Sleep (Time)
 
End Sub

